# how to read mails with attached from MS exchange with java mail and EWS

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have a problem when I use javamail4ews-0.0.8 for reading  mails from MS exchange server 2010
I connect successful
and I read every mail that I have but  when I try to see the attachment I only can't see nothing.
I look the contentType his valor is  "text/plain" and when I read the getContent().getClass() is String. if I see the information that contain the text/plain this mentioned that is a MimeMultipart beacause have the leyend MIME-Version: 1.0

I look my mail and  contain a PDF and XML

I don't know why the program return me a contentType="text/plain" and getContent().getClass()=String

I need one Multipart or MimeMultipart but I don't know how to convert that.

I add my code ....

Thanks guys.

```
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Store;
public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args){
 StoreMail test = new StoreMail(
         "user",
         "password",
         "https://<exchangeServer>/ews/exchange.asmx",
         "ewsstore",
         "C:\\");
 //public StoreMail( String userMail, String passMail, String host, String protocolo, String directorio) {
 try {
    test.readEmails(1);
 } catch (MessagingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
}
```

and

```
public class StoreMail {    
public StoreMail( String userMail, String passMail, String host, String protocolo, String directorio) {
    ....
}
public void readEmails( int cantidad ) throws MessagingException {  
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("directorio","C:\\BASURA\\\\" );
    props.setProperty("dircliente","C:\\BASURA\\\\" );
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

    System.out.println( host+" "+userMail+" "+passMail );
    Store store = session.getStore(protocolo);
    store.connect(host, userMail, passMail);

    Folder currFolder = store.getDefaultFolder();
    Message[] messages = currFolder.getMessages();
    for (Message message : messages) {
        try {
                Object body = message.getContent();
                System.out.println("BODY:::::"+body.getClass()); // is class java.lang.String
                if (body instanceof Multipart) { // or instanceof MimeMultipart
                    System.out.println( " MimeMultipart" );
                    procMultipart((Multipart) body)
                } else {
                    System.out.println(" other:");
                    procPart(message);
                }   


        }catch (Throwable thrbl) {
                thrbl.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
public void procPart( Part p ) {
    try {
        String contentType = p.getContentType();

        if ( contentType != null ){
            //if (p.isMimeType("multipart/alternative")) {
                //System.out.println("is multipart/alternative");
            //}else{
                if ( contentType.toLowerCase().startsWith( "multipart/" ) ) {
                    procMultipart(( Multipart ) p)
                }else{
                    if(contentType.toLowerCase().startsWith( "text/plain" )){
                        //I don't know what to do because is a Mime Multipart... and I need to read it
                        // I need transform the attached to PDF and XML and Save it
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("other contentType"+contentType);
                        String nomfich = p.getFileName();
                        if (nomfich != null) {
                            if( nomfich.toLowerCase().endsWith( ".xml" ) ) {
                                System.out.println(" XML octet-stream nomfich: " + nomfich);
                                saveArchXML( p.getInputStream() );

                            } else if( nomfich.toLowerCase().endsWith( ".pdf" ) ) {
                                saveArchPDF( p.getInputStream(),nomfich.toLowerCase() );
                            } else if( nomfich.toLowerCase().endsWith( ".zip" ) ) {
                                saveArchZIP( p.getInputStream(),nomfich.toLowerCase() );
                            }else{

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            //}
        }
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void procMultipart(Multipart mp) throws MessagingException {
    for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
        logger.info(" procMultipart :" + i);
        Part p = mp.getBodyPart(i);
        procPart(p);
    }
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn a lot more about internet email and MIME messages.  Start with these JavaMail FAQ entries:

- [Where can I learn the basics about Internet email that I'll need to know to program JavaMail effectively?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#basics)
- [Where can I find some example programs that show how to use JavaMail?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#examples)
- [How do I find the main message body in a message that has attachments?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody)

In particular, see the msgshow.java demo program available from the link above.

Answer (score 0):

With JWebServices for Exchange it looks easy

[Find messages with attachments](http://www.independentsoft.de/jwebservices/tutorial/findmessageswithattachments.html)